# AWS Ubuntu EC2 Instance Error: ZipArchive::close(): Failure to create temporary file: Permission denied

Tags: amazon-ec2, file-upload, laravel-10

I have tried checking php.ini files /tmp is the folder where temporary files are stored. I checked the permissions. It has 777 permission. Here is my sample code. Please help. I am using an AWS EC2 instance. The project is in Laravel 10. The code works perfectly in other hosting services.

```
public function download_zip($uid)
{
    $zip = new ZipArchive;
    $fileName = 'myfiles_'.$uid.'.zip';

    if ($zip->open(public_path($fileName), ZipArchive::CREATE) === true) {
        $files = Filelists::where('uid', $uid)->get();

        foreach ($files as $key => $value) {
            $relativeNameInZipFile = $value->filename;
            $zip->addFile('storage/uploads/'.$value->filename, "$value->filename");
        }

        $zip->close();
        
        return response()->download(public_path($fileName));
    }
}
```